# How to add image texture material to all parts of maze?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am new to blender and I am using the latest version 2.8, and I have been trying to apply an image texture in material for a maze that I am making. I have found a question similar to mine but it seems that our approaches was different. First off, I did not create the maze from scratch, it was an svg downloaded from a mazegenerator(http://www.mazegenerator.net/). I just scaled it ,shade flat, recalculate normals and and added a solidifier modifier(dont whether all this is needed to tell, but just wanna be thorough). In the end it looked like this:[image]
My first problem was when I subdivided it, it only did it on one side shown below: [image]
I dont want that to happen, I wanted it to be on all sides.
The second problem was when I entered the image texture in the material tab and clicked display render preview, it only went darker but no image was shown and it wasnt even in the uv editor(it usually automatically appears): [image]
Am I doing this right or is there a better way? I used this cause I could make a maze as fast as possible or do I have no choice but to make a maze from scratch.
I did find a maze generator on blender called ultimazePro but I cannot get it to work, I already added it on tools but I dont know where to generate it: [image]

Also I cannot seem to export this to unity as well for some reason, the option for FBX.fbx or wavefront.obj is not there. I am sorry if I have made any mistakes, and your help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You might just need to apply the Modifiers. But I strongly suggest you try UV texturing the default Cube to get feel for the process.

Comment: Hello. Your approach seems pretty good, but as @rob said, you'll need to apply the solidify modifier before subdividing the mesh. Please, share your .blend file, so others could take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: @JachymMichal I have just added the blend file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues.
They are easy to repair, but will take some time.

---

1) Your original maze contains overlayed geometry.
That's a big problem in 3D modelling.
You will need to clean it up. It's technically very easy, but might take some time.

*Clean up overlayed geometry and connect all vertices like this.*
[image]

2) Keep quads whenever possible.
I cannot overstate this - this maze is begging to be made of quads.
Quads will allow you to use loopcuts and other useful features to speed up your workflow.

3) Keep scale to 1.
After transforms, go to *Object->Apply-Scale*.
This will ensure that UV mapping works properly.

*Your current maze mesh has a messed up scale.* 
[image]

4) Use Solidify modifier to adjust the height of your maze.
You just need to *Apply the modifier* before subdivision or UV mapping.

5) Use Smart UV project for UV unwrapping.
This function is well suited for complex geometric shapes such as your maze.

[Here is a page from Blender Manual explaining Smart UV project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html).

[image]

Good luck.
If you have any questions, let me know.

Here is your edited Blendfile.
I separated the bottom part of your maze and connected a few overlayed faces.
[image]

Comment: Took me a while to understand your steps, but once finished it worked!! thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Glad to be of service. Welcome aboard :).